# No matter what I do, I always get "Unsupported version of Gradle"

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

There are dozens of tutorials how to fix error `The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.`, but neither of them work for me. I always get an error:

`The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)`

It does not even say which Gradle I should use which other people get!

I am using Android Studio 0.9.1 and I am trying to open a Gradle project which was dependent on Gradle 0.12.+ (the line in `build.gradle` says

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'`)

I changed this to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'` but still got the same error.

Then I went to `<project>/gradle/wrapper` and edited file `gradle-wrapper.properties` to say `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.14-all.zip`. This did NOT help either.

Then I went to each subdirectory and found all `build.gradle` files, including such files for Facebook and other libraries, and changed the line:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
...
```

but this did NOT work either.

So I am clueless now as all tutorials propose either of solutions I tried.

Why I cannot import this project? Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I don't think it is your issue, but you should use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` instead of `apply plugin: 'android'`

Answer (score 0):

Version '0.14.+' of the gradle plugin requires Gradle 2.1, as mentioned in [the official docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). It seems that you're trying to use 1.14

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.14-all.zip
```

which is not compatible.

The easiest way to fix is problem is by downloading Gradle 2.1 and running the build directly with it, or by changing your wrapper to use 2.1 instead of 1.14.